# How can Malekith create the Aether?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: The Dark World* Odin explains the origin of the aether as

> Their leader, Malekith, **made a weapon out of that darkness**, it was called the Aether. While the other relics often appear as stones, the Aether is fluid, and ever changing. It changes matter into dark matter, and seeks out host bodies, drawing strength from their life force. Malekith sought to use the Aether’s power to return the universe to one of darkness. But, after eternities of bloodshed, my father Bor finally triumphed; ushering in a peace that lasted thousands of years.

I didn't think that Malekith was a titan/an eternal - as such, how can someone like him posses the power to create an Infinity Stone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**He didn't *create* an Infinity Stone - he created a weapon *out of* an Infinity Stone.**

And this isn't even the first time we've seen that done, nor the last. Some other examples of this or something similar happening include;

- The Red Skull using the Tesseract (later revealed to be the Space Gem) to power weapons in *Captain America: The First Avenger*,
- Loki's scepter harnessing the Mind Gem to control people's minds in *Avengers Assemble*,
- Baron Von Strucker using Loki's scepter to give superpowers to Wanda and Pietro Maximoff in a post-credits sequence for *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*,
- Ronan the accuser embedding the Power Gem in his warhammer in *Guardians of the Galaxy*,
- Ultron (and later, Tony Stark and Bruce Banner) using the Mind Gem as part of The Vision in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

As such, it isn't particularly difficult to believe that the leader of the Dark Elves wouldn't be able to turn the Reality Gem into a weapon in the form of the Aether when so many other people have done similar.

Comment: All the examples are correct, but they are tool to harness powers of stone. Dialogue says, he creates a weapon from **darkness** and this is called as **aether**

Comment: @Rajesh We don't know exactly what he did to turn the Reality Gem into the Aether. My point here is that he didn't *create* the Aether, he turned the Reality Gem *into* the Aether, and that it isn't the only instance of people using the Infinity Stones in various ways. I don't find it unbelievable that an ancient race of aliens who went to war with Asgard don't know more about the Infinity Stones than mere humans, who have also managed to do quite a lot with them in the short time that they've even known they exist.

Comment: So are you implying Reality stone is something different and **Aether** is just a deduced weapon/tool to harness its power?

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, and that's supported by the images of the stones that we see when The Collector is explaining what Infinity Stones are to Rocket, Groot, Star Lord and Gamora in *Guardians of the Galaxy*. We see all 6 Infinity Stones in stone form at one point, as well as seeing them in their current forms (Aether and Tesseract) slightly later on.

Comment: Wow! I will have to see Guardians again.. :-D Thanks

Comment: Downvote cause there are no gems in the MCU

Comment: @cde I'm not sure if I follow. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Stones, not gems. They changed the names in the MCU.